# How to limit physical memory in python3?

Tags: python, memory, limit, virtual-memory

I am trying to limit the memory usage of a python script, so it gets killed if it exceeds a threshold.

I tried using `resource.setrlimit` but the module seems to be limited.

`resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_RSS,...)` doesn't seem to work on newer Linux kernels.

`resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS,...)` works but it also counts virtual and shared memory, thus killing the process when it doesn't need to.

I need a solution that works directly in python, without using control groups or other tools.

Any way I might achieve this?

Comment: User mode processes have almost no ability to control the use of physical memory, only virtual.